# How-tos related to SQL Developer Generate Doc

Tags: oracle, automation, documentation

I have been using SQL Developer option "Generate DB Doc" which is an awesome feature as it generates a beautiful doc but it is a pain that it is not synchronized (You need to regenerate from `sqldeveloper`).

I was wondering:

- How to generate that doc from the command line so it can be automated?
- How to generate the doc of a schema that I do not own but that I have access to?

Answer (score 1):

SQLDeveloper 4:
sdcli.exe gives access to the command line API. But only these features are available:

```
D:\Develop\SQLDeveloper4.0.0.13.30\sqldeveloper\sqldeveloper\bin>sdcli.exe
Available features:
cart: Database Cart Batch Tasks
dba: Basic Batch DBA Tasks
format: SQL Format Task
migration: Database Migration Tasks
reports: Basic Batch Reporting Tasks
unittest: Unit Testing Batch Tasks
```

So I don't think it's possible. Generate DB Doc would be a good addition. Please post an enhancement request ;-)

Comment: Let's see what happens ;-) This is an option that would be very handy. Generate DB Docs automaticly periodically and publish them for Developers/Architects/etc.